# PostgreSQL create table with auto compute columns from different table columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have the following tables, and want to create table `card` where the columns `fee` is calculated as `product_price.price + product_sale.b_rate` 
and `comm` computed is `product_price.price - product_sale.s_rate`

is there a way to autopopulate the table `card` when table `product_sale` and `product_price` populates.

such as create table `card` with computed column or function?

need help

```
product_sale
+---------+-------------+----+
| column  |    type     | pk |
+---------+-------------+----+
| s_date  | date        | Y  |
| seller  | varchar(50) | Y  |
| country | varchar(50) | Y  |
| b_rate  | float       |    |
| s_rate  | float       |    |
+---------+-------------+----+

product_price
+---------+-------------+----+
| column  |    type     | pk |
+---------+-------------+----+
| p_date  | date        | Y  |
| product | varchar(50) | Y  |
| price   | varchar(50) |    |
+---------+-------------+----+


card
+---------+-------------+----+
| column  |    type     | pk |
+---------+-------------+----+
| c_date  | date        | Y  |
| seller  | varchar(50) | Y  |
| country | varchar(50) | Y  |
| fee     | float       |    |
| comm    | float       |    |
+---------+-------------+----+
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a view?

Comment: Reconsider using `float` for currency and for percentages. Normally, I'd expect to see an arbitrary-precision numeric type like [decimal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

Answer (score 0):

You can have "pseudo" virtual columns, not bona fide real ones. PostgreSQL can emulate virtual columns as functions on a table (not persisted), However,  There are several limitations:

- Virtual columns can only depend on values on the same row of the same table and/or generic database functions, not other rows of other tables.
- They are not listed automatically when using * on a select. See [Emulating Virtual Columns](http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/11/postgres-virtual-columns/).
- They cannot be indexed. Meaning, if you want to search by them the search is less than optimal.

Now, I guess the first item is a deal breaker for you. This is not what you need.

I've used this trick quite successfully several times already.